# How do I parse data sent from QR Scanner

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing an application that takes text data sent from a QR code scan and performs a lookup from [the CDC crosswalk tables](https://www2a.cdc.gov/vaccines/iis/iisstandards/vaccines.asp?rpt=ndc). Here is a sample:

```
0110358160825436172302061095EJ7
```

The string data posted above contains the NDC number, vaccine lot number, and expiration date. However, I don't know how to parse out those fields.

How can I do this?

Comment: How sends you the QR code scan? - I think you need to talk to the people who give you this requirement and ask for clarifications to them.

Comment: `10358160825436` could be the "Use GTIN" field from that data set. I see that value where SequenceNumber = 308. I don't see any other matches. I agree with Marco, someone should be able to tell you how to interpret the data.

Comment: https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/programs/iis/2d-barcodes/implementation-toolkit.html May be a good source?

Comment: Thanks to @Fildor, page 19 of this link might be what we are looking for: https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/programs/iis/2d-barcodes/downloads/toolkit-adminstration-technical-implementation-guide-508.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It sort of does assuming every file is sent in the same format.  Since I don't know much about barcodes, is there some type of markers within the data to tell the format?

Comment: Based on Page 19 of the Technical Implementation Guide: Vaccine Administration, I'm getting GS1 AppID:`01`, GTIN:`10358160825436`, GS1 AppID:`17`, YYMMDD:`230206`, GS1 AppID:`10`, Lot#`95EJ7`.  Is that how everyone else is reading it?

Comment: You are correct.  Let me scan a few more types.  Perhaps I just need to assume everything is in this format.  Hate making those assumptions without being sure.

Comment: FYI: Added regex versions to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is PowerShell code that does the job.  Below is what should work in C# code.

```
$QRScan = '0110358160825436172302061095EJ7';
$GS1AppID1 = $QRScan.Substring(0,2);
$GTIN = $QRScan.Substring(2,14);
$GS1AppID2 = $QRScan.Substring(16,2);
$YYMMDD = $QRScan.Substring(18,6);
$GS1AppID3 = $QRScan.Substring(24,2); 
$LotNumber = $QRScan.Substring(26);

Write-Host "GS1AppID1: $GS1AppID1"
Write-Host "GTIN: $GTIN"
Write-Host "GS1AppID2: $GS1AppID2"
Write-Host "YYMMDD: $YYMMDD"
Write-Host "GS1AppID3: $GS1AppID3"
Write-Host "LotNumber: $LotNumber"
```

This is the output:

```
GS1AppID1: 01
GTIN: 10358160825436
GS1AppID2: 17
YYMMDD: 230206
GS1AppID3: 10
LotNumber: 95EJ7
```

I haven't tested in C#, but it should be very close to what you need.

```
string QRScan = "0110358160825436172302061095EJ7";
string GS1AppID1 = QRScan.Substring(0,2);
string GTIN = QRScan.Substring(2,14);
string GS1AppID2 = QRScan.Substring(16,2);
string YYMMDD = QRScan.Substring(18,6);
string GS1AppID3 = QRScan.Substring(24,2); 
string LotNumber = QRScan.Substring(26);
```

**NOTE:** [Substring can throw errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0), so keep that in mind as you use it in your code.

### Regex Versions

While Substring does the job, the question was tagged regex.

Regex C# console version (First time doing regex named groups in C# - Is there a simpler way?):

```
static void Main() {
    string RE = @"^(?<GS1AppID1>\d{2})(?<GTIN>\d{14})(?<GS1AppID2>\d{2})(?<YYMMDD>\d{6})(?<GS1AppID3>\d{2})(?<LotNumber>\w+)$";
    var Parser = new Regex(RE);
    string QRScan = "0110358160825436172302061095EJ7";
    Match Matches = Parser.Match(QRScan);
    if(Matches.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine("GS1AppID1: {0}", Matches.Groups["GS1AppID1"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("GTIN: {0}", Matches.Groups["GTIN"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("GS1AppID2: {0}", Matches.Groups["GS1AppID2"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("YYMMDD: {0}", Matches.Groups["YYMMDD"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("GS1AppID3: {0}", Matches.Groups["GS1AppID3"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("LotNumber: {0}", Matches.Groups["LotNumber"].Value);
    }
}
```

Regex PowerShell (Just for comparison.):

```
$RE = '^(?<GS1AppID1>\d{2})(?<GTIN>\d{14})(?<GS1AppID2>\d{2})(?<YYMMDD>\d{6})(?<GS1AppID3>\d{2})(?<LotNumber>\w+)$';
$QRScan = '0110358160825436172302061095EJ7';
if($QRScan -match $RE) {
    Write-Host "GS1AppID1: $($Matches.GS1AppID1)"
    Write-Host "GTIN: $($Matches.GTIN)"
    Write-Host "GS1AppID2: $($Matches.GS1AppID2)"
    Write-Host "YYMMDD: $($Matches.YYMMDD)"
    Write-Host "GS1AppID3: $($Matches.GS1AppID3)"
    Write-Host "LotNumber: $($Matches.LotNumber)"
}
```